# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc

I have chunk of code to retrieve documents from mongodb database. It works fine in normal java project(with public static void main), but when I am trying same chunk of code in Sprig-MVC application I am getting

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.BsonBinaryReader.(Lorg/bson/io/BsonInput;)V}, caused by {java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.BsonBinaryReader.(Lorg/bson/io/BsonInput;)V}}]"*** Exception message..

**Following is the Log:**

> Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/temp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.BsonBinaryReader.(Lorg/bson/io/BsonInput;)V}, caused by {java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.BsonBinaryReader.(Lorg/bson/io/BsonInput;)V}}]] with root cause
>   com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.BsonBinaryReader.(Lorg/bson/io/BsonInput;)V}, caused by {java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.BsonBinaryReader.(Lorg/bson/io/BsonInput;)V}}]
>       at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:370)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:101)
>       at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.(ClusterBinding.java:75)
>       at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.(ClusterBinding.java:71)
>       at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getReadConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:63)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:166)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:394)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:57)
>       at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:738)
>       at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:725)
>       at com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl$FindOperationIterable.first(FindIterableImpl.java:197)
>       at com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:140)

Following is the java code:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bson.Document;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

import pojos.LoginCredentials;

public class LoginDAO {

private LoginCredentials logindata;


public LoginDAO(LoginCredentials logindata){

    this.logindata=logindata;


}

        public String retrievedPassword(){

               MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );

                 MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("progressreport");

                 MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("studentprofile");

                Document cursor = coll.find().first();
            System.out.println(cursor.toString());
            return cursor.getString("password");
        }
}
```

Comment: What is your driver version? I think you should checkout the newest one. I have got the same problem too and update solves it.

Comment: Yess.. you are right, the problem was with the jar version, its been resolved, btw thank you for your reply.